# How to compile mex file in matlab 2014a, visual studio 2017 and win10?

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, compilation, mex

I'm trying to compile a mex file using MATLAB 2014a. It returns an error `No compiler found` and I try `mex -setup` but it cannot find any compiler while I have installed `Visual Studio 2017'.

I'm using Win10 and I don't know how to fix this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a version of MATLAB that isn't supported on your OS (it is supported up to Windows 8.1), and a version of MSVC that didn't exist when it was released (it only recognizes MSVC versions 2008-2013).

However, it is supposed to have `lcc-win32` bundled with it, which is a simple C compiler, and should be found by `mex -setup`.

If you want to compile C++ MEX-files, you will need to find MSVC 2013 or upgrade your version of MATLAB (highly recommended at this point).

Answer (score 2):

Have you check whether your system is compatible or supported each other?
You may refer here https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.html